# How do I avoid getting a newline to be inserted into my char array using stringbuilder

Tags: c#, arrays, newline, stringbuilder, environment

I am importing a text file to a string and afterwards I set it into a char array using stringbuilder, but my problem is that newline also is inserted into the char array. If I use this n\ then the element that should be on index 21 will be on index 22, and if I use Environment.NewLine then the element that should be on index 21 will be on index 23 and the same goes with AppendLine(). I by the way added an image of how the output window looks like [labyrinth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUXk6.png)   [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUXk6.png). How do I make a new line but without placing it in the char array?
My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.IO;

using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication25

{
class Program


{

    static char[] FloridaArray;
    static string DenverString;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Increase Console Buffer Height
        Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

        DenverString = ConvertStringArrayToString();
        FloridaArray = DenverString.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(DenverString);
        Console.WriteLine(FloridaArray[43]);
        for (int i = 0; i < FloridaArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get character from array.
            char letter = FloridaArray[i];
            // Display each letter.
            Console.Write(i + " Letter: ");
            Console.WriteLine(letter);
        }
    }

    static string ConvertStringArrayToString()
    {
        // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var value in File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
        {


            builder.Append(value);

            builder.Append('\n');

            //builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            //builder.AppendLine();
            //builder.Append("\r\n");
            //builder.Append("\r");




        }

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}


}
```

[image: output]

[image: labyrinth]

Comment: Are you saying you want to read the entire file into a string, without any newline characters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems as though you both want and do not want a newline. If you want to output a newline, you can do so manually with a Console.Write(), and simple add no newlines to your character objects/arrays. \n and Environment.Newline can differ in character length because \n is the line terminator for Unix systems, and \r\n is that of Windows. You can do a

```
String.Split()
```

if you ever want to strip newlines from a character string, but that returns an array of substings, some of which may be empty, but which gives you more flexibility. What you'd more likely want is

```
 String.Trim()
```

, which is also effective and probably a more direct approach. It will remove all characters from the beginning of a string that are whitespace classified(newls among them), and the same from the end back, meaning internal whitespace is preserved. Please clarify if you want newlines in your data structures or solely your output.

EDIT:

```
 //FloridaArray exists as char array with newlines

///make vector that can hold florida char elements without resize
List<char> tempFloridaCharList = new List<char>(FloridaArray.Length)
//declare container for florida characters minus newline
char[] newlinelessFloridaArray; 

foreach(char i in FloridaArray)
{
    if(i== '\r' || i== '\n')
        continue;
    tempFloridaCharList.Add(i);
}
//you now have all characters that arent newline from FLorida array
 in a list which you can immediately convert to an array.
newlinelessFloridaArray = tempFloridaCharList.ToArray();
//if you dont need the old florida array with \n anymore, you can say:
FloridaArray = tempFloridaCharList.ToArray();

//When youre happy, clear the tempCharList so it can be used again
tempFloridaCharList.Clear();
```

Comment: Like the others I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. 
Try replacing builder.Append(value); with builder.Append(value.Trim()); and remove the line after it.

Comment: I think the key is that I make an if statement in the for loop saying if(FloridaArray[i] != '\n') {proceed putting elements from FloridaArray into char letter} else {do nothing} And then i++ at the end of the if statement? How would that pseudo code look like in c# ?

Comment: @cop77 I added a suggestion on how to take your existing char array with newlines, and produce one with all the characters in original order minus the newlines. Let me know if it's helpful

Comment: @schulmaster it looks like we came up with almost the same answer, so I can only give you a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I simply just transferred the array without the \n into a list. The code is found below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.IO;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{

class Program


{

    static char[] FloridaArray;

    static string DenverString;
    static List<string> wrd = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Increase Console Buffer Height
        Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

        DenverString = ConvertStringArrayToString();



        FloridaArray = DenverString.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(DenverString);

        for (int i = 0; i < DenverString.Length; i++)
        {

            if (FloridaArray[i] != '\n')
            {

                wrd.Add(FloridaArray[i].ToString());
                // Get character from array.
                char letter = FloridaArray[i];
                // Display each letter.
                //Console.Write(i + " Letter: ");
                //Console.WriteLine(letter);

               }
        }
        foreach (String o in wrd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(wrd[21]);

    }

    static string ConvertStringArrayToString()
    {
        // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var value in File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
        {


            builder.Append(value);

            builder.Append('\n');

            //builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            //builder.AppendLine();
            //builder.Append("\r\n");
            //builder.Append("\r");




        }

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
 }
```